# how to mix streams api and observables?

Tags: javascript, stream, observable

I am reading from a serial port using streams api and would like to emit the value that I read from the port using an observable.

```
while(port.readable){
  const reader = port.readable.getReader();
  while(true){
    const { value, done } = await reader.read();
    if (done) {
       break;
    }

    obs.next(value);
  }
}
```

the next value never gets emitted. Can anybody show me what is wrong here?